# Cloud Init can't create Apt source from k8s.io due to 302 redirect

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, apt, vagrant, cloud-init

I'm attempting to add the k8s.io apt package source to a VM using cloud-init, but the URL provided from [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/08/15/pkgs-k8s-io-introduction/) does a 302 redirect, and gpg doesn't like that.

cloud-init config.yml:

```
    apt:
      sources:
        docker:
          keyid: '9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88'
          keyserver: 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg'
          source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic stable'
        kubernetes:
          keyid: 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436'
          keyserver: 'https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key'
          source: 'deb [signed-by=$KEY_FILE] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/ /'
      conf: |
        APT {
            Get {
                Assume-Yes 'true';
                Fix-Broken 'true';
            }
        }
```

Error from VM's `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`:

```
2023-12-10 18:29:02,444 - gpg.py[ERROR]: Failed to obtain gpg key DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/gpg.py", line 101, in recv_key
    naplen = next(sleeps)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/gpg.py", line 130, in getkeybyid
    recv_key(keyid, keyserver=keyserver)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/gpg.py", line 109, in recv_key
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to import key 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436' from keyserver 'https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key' after 3 tries: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['gpg', '--no-tty', '--keyserver=https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key', '--recv-keys', 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436']
Exit code: 2
Reason: -
Stdout: 
Stderr: gpg: WARNING: unacceptable HTTP redirect from server was cleaned up
        gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
2023-12-10 18:29:02,465 - gpg.py[WARNING]: Failed delete key "DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436": Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['gpg', '--batch', '--yes', '--delete-keys', 'DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436']
Exit code: 2
Reason: -
Stdout: 
Stderr: gpg: key "DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436" not found: Not found
        gpg: DE15B14486CD377B9E876E1A234654DA9A296436: delete key failed: Not found
2023-12-10 18:29:02,466 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module apt_configure (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_apt_configure' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_apt_configure.py'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu2 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 10 Dec 2023 18:29:02 +0000. Up 23.60 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu2 finished at Sun, 10 Dec 2023 18:29:02 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNoCloud [seed=/dev/sr0][dsmode=net].  Up 23.74 seconds
```

```
$ curl https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The URL

```
https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key
```

redirects to:

```
https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key
```

Now, I can change to `keyserver` location to the redirected URL, but that could change.  Is there a way to tell gpg to follow the redirect using additional cloud-init configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting from the `keyserver` URL in the cloud-init configuration might cause gpg to fail and prevent Kubernetes apt source from being added. Changing the URL to the redirect might work temporarily, it's not ideal as the redirect target could change in the future, breaking your setup.

Here are some options that you can consider to handle redirect and add the Kubernetes apt source.

Option 1: Use the redirected URL directly:

- Update your cloud-init configuration to use the redirected URL (https://prod-cdn.packages.k8s.io/repositories/isv:/kubernetes:/core:/stable:/v1.28/deb/Release.key) for the keyserver.
- This solution is simple and avoids relying on gpg following redirects, but it depends on the redirect remaining stable in the future.

Option 2: Configure gpg to follow redirects:

- gpg doesn't have a built-in option to automatically follow redirects, but you can work around it using a script or wrapper.
- One approach is to write a short script that retrieves the redirected URL dynamically and then calls gpg with the updated URL.
- Alternatively, consider using a tool like `wget` to download the key file from the redirected URL and then pass it to gpg using the `--import` option.

Hope this information helps you find a solution to handle the redirect and successfully add the Kubernetes apt source to your cloud-init configuration.

Comment: Well, I'm not using gpg directly.  The cloud-init config instructs cloud-init on the VM to create a apt source, so it's really cloud-init that's making use to gpg.  The only solution appears to use the redirect url directly and hope that it doesn't break in the future.